# Scrollable area related to the size of another element

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

I want to create a scrollable area for the text (class `text`), who have the size of the picture (class `picture`).

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="..." >
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only way, I have found is set the size for the `wrapper` but if the picture have height more importe than the wrapper, she is crop.

So make it's possible to realize a scroll area for `text` with the size of `picture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed they are columns. Not possible for rows with CSS.

Try this, if you have extra paragraphs wrap them in a div and change the selector accordingly.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.picture,
.text {
  flex: 1; /* example */
  position: relative;
}

.text p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I want. I'm not sur to understand what is the behavior of `flex: 1;`... It's fix the elements with the same number in the same level?

Comment: The `flex` property is more or less like `width` in the example, I suggest you to learn flexbox today.

Comment: I noticed that flex was a "fashion"? more efficient? 
I see Bootstrap has totally switched to flex for version 4. So I think I'm going to look at it seriously. Thank you for your time and your advice about flex.